# Not understanding why JNIEnv->GetFieldID Fails

Tags: java, java-native-interface

In java I have:

```
package com.mypkg.utils;
...

public class attitude_calculator
{
    private long native_ptr_;
    ...
    public native RealMatrix R();
}
```

In the jni layer I need to get access to `native_ptr_`. Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL 
Java_com_mypkg_utils_attitude_1calculator_R(JNIEnv *jenv,
                                            jobject jobj)
{
  myns::AttitudeCalculator *nobj = nullptr;
  jlong addr = 0;
  jfieldID jfid = 0;
  jclass jcls;

  jcls = jenv->GetObjectClass(jobj);
  jfid = jenv->GetFieldID(jcls, "native_ptr_",
    "Lcom/mypkg/utils/attitude_calculator$native_ptr_;");
  if (jfid == nullptr || jfid == NULL) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Calling `GetFieldID` results in a

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError.

What is the correct way to call `GetFieldID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`native_ptr_` is a `long`, hence its signature is `"J"`, *not* `"Lcom/mypkg/utils/attitude_calculator$native_ptr_;"`.

So the call should be:

```
jfid = jenv->GetFieldID(jcls, "native_ptr_", "J");
```

Comment: Where in the documentation are those strings listed? It would be nice to have as a reference so I don't have to ask in the future unless it is something really non-trivial.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html  scroll down to **Type Signatures**.

Comment: Or, `javap -v -s com.mypkg.utils.attitude_calculator | grep -A 1 "native_ptr_"` You can drop the -v for a method signature.